# JSF form validation and update

Tags: jsf-2

I have a complex form that contains a selectonemenu from where I select a value that I use to add in a table. The problem is that I can't make it work when the validation on all the fields are validated. I tried multiple sollutions but I can't make it work. I would appreciate if someone could guide me  because I'm not very experienced but very eager to learn. thx in advaned

```
<h:form class="add-form">
            <div class="row">                   
                <fieldset class="col-sm-3 col-md-3"><!-- personal info fields -->   
                <legend>Personal Information</legend>               
                <div class="required"> 
                    <label>First Name</label>
                    <h:inputText value="#{candidateBean.firstName}"></h:inputText>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9">             
                    <div class="required"> 
                        <label>Select Working City</label>
                        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{candidateBean.city}" converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter">
                            <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="-- select one --" />
                            <f:selectItems value="#{settingsBean.settings.citiesListVO.workingCityVO}" var="cities" itemValue="#{cities}" itemLabel="#{cities.name}"/>
                        </h:selectOneMenu>
                    </div>      
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3"> 
                    <div class="required">                
                        <label>Add</label>         
                        <h:commandLink type="button" class="btn btn-primary form-control input-sm"
                            title="Add"
                            ajax="false"
                            href="#!"
                            actionListener="#{candidateBean.addWorkingCity}">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                        </h:commandLink>                
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div><!-- working cities inputs -->                    
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 required">
                    <label>Current Working Cities:</label><br></br> 
                    <h:dataTable
                        class="table table-condensed"
                        value="#{candidateBean.workingCities}" var="currentCity">
                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="City Name" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{currentCity.name}" />
                        </h:column>
                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Options"></h:outputText>
                            </f:facet>
                                <h:commandLink type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"
                                    title="Remove"
                                    ajax="false"
                                    actionListener="#{candidateBean.removeWorkingCity}">
                                        <f:attribute name="selected" value="#{currentCity}"/>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                                </h:commandLink>
                        </h:column>
                    </h:dataTable>
                </div><!-- column -->
                </div><!-- workingCity table row -->
```

This is the initial code. I have tried all kinds of solutions like ayax updated but I didn't succed. I'm sorry if I didn't explian enough. Please ask for more info

Comment: -1 because you need to spend more time explaining your code and what you tried to do. All you said was that you had a problem with validation and you tried a few solutions. What solutions? What do you mean by validation problem?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your Add link with code below

```
<h:commandLink actionListener="#{candidateBean.addWorkingCity}"
           styleClass="btn btn-primary form-control input-sm"
           title="Add">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add
</h:commandLink>
```

Tag **commandLink** does not have attributes like **class** or **href**. Instead of attribute **class** use **styleClass**, instead of **href** use **action**. Form more information read [commandLink documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/h/commandLink.html).

To remove item from table I would use action instead of actionListener:

```
<h:commandLink title="Remove"
           styleClass="btn btn-primary btn-xs"
           action="#{candidateBean.removeWorkingCity(currentCity)}"
           >
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Remove
</h:commandLink>
```

and in your CandidateBean:

```
public void removeWorkingCity(City c) {
    workingCities.remove(c);
}
```

Make sure that CandidateBean is ViewScoped or wider.